# Generating a dynamic size dynamic container with STL algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I would like to generate a container of elements of unknown size using `STL` algorithm header. I want to avoid writing my own `loop`. The motivation behind this is writing expressive and safe code, as argued by Kate Gregory in Beautiful C++ on Pluralsight.

My approach so far is limited to containers of known `size`. ( I'm talking about dynamic containers).

Example :

```
int expected_container_size = 10;

std::vector<int> dynamic_container;
dynamic_container.reserve(expected_container_size);

auto example_iota_generator = [n = 0]()mutable{return ++n; };

std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(dynamic_container), expected_container_size, example_iota_generator);
```

To repeat the question :

Can `STL` algorithms be used to generate a non fixed size dynamic container?
For example a fibonacci sequence whos `last/largest` element `value` is less than some `const n`;

Thank you in advance!

Comment: IMHO, a named function like `generate_fib_seq_up_to_n` is more expressive and you can just put your loop in there.

Comment: It's more of a mental let's write good code as instructed challenge, but yes your suggestion would be my regular approach. @NathanOliver

Comment: I don't see how my question is unclear. Please help me improve it @Ron

Comment: Are you worried more about overallocating, reallocating or calculating the length of the sequence?

Comment: Looks like you need to use range library https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3

Comment: Well, fair question. I'm a novice and a chill person so i'm not worried about anything :))). But my approach would be to make a rough overestimation of the upperbound of the vec size and reserve that, and then go generating. I want lenght calculation to be a part of the lambda - something i would normaly do with a while loop. I hope i answered your question. @Caleth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand upon @Slava's comment, with the [Range V3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html#range-views) library, you can do something like:

```
auto gen = [n = 0]() mutable { return ++n; };
auto filter = [](int val){ return val < 100; };
auto iotas = ranges::view::generate(gen) | ranges::action::take_while(filter);
std::vector<int> nums{ iotas.begin(), iotas.end() }; // 0, 1, 2, ... 99
```

Comment: Thanks, i guess STL is limited in that way. I'm not sure if to expand my knowledge with such libs as Range V3 as of now, or to keep mastering(learning) STL. But this question doesn't belong on stack overflow :))

Comment: @AntonioDropulić The ranges library exists to demonstrate the viability of a proposal for a future version of the standard, perhaps C++20. It isn't a replacement for `<algorithm>`

Answer (score 2):

> Can STL algorithms be used to generate a non fixed size dynamic container? For example a fibonacci sequence whos last/largest element value is less than some const n;

You can indeed use the algorithms to generate content into any container whether the container is dynamically sized, or not.

Comment: I've used the wrong word. I have edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: I'm aware that i can do that, as I have done in my example. The problem is that to std::generate_n takes a const int as the second argument representative of the container size. Dynamic containers offer the benefit of just needing a declaration before generation, so no double creation is done. 

I guess my question needs better frazing. You are free to edit my question if you have the right wording. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @AntonioDropulić second argument of `std::generate_n` is not `const`. I don't understand what "double creation" you talk about. What is created twice?

Comment: I was wrong. To talk about a specific example, i'll use std::array. Since you can't declare std::array<some_obj,size> array; but intstead you have to use std::array<some_obj, size> array(); I thought that the objects are default constructed, and an array cant be constructed with objects not default constructible. I don't know why i thought that tbh. I checked and it obviously doesn' happen.

Comment: I have accepted the other answer. I don't think you answer my question. Consider the following code. It does complie but doesnt do what you would expect it (iota to infinity) .
Here is the modified lambda from my question.
 `auto example_iota_generator = [&, n = 0]()mutable{
  ++expected_container_size;
  return ++n; };`

Comment: @AntonioDropulić Your question appears to be specifically about dynamically sized containers, so how is `std::array` relevant? You *can* in fact declare `std::array<some_obj,size> array;`. In such declaration `some_obj` must be default constructible indeed, but that's not required if you use aggregate initialization for all subobjects.

Comment: Your answer statement is correct, but the dynamic container size is determined on the algorithm call, so it is hardly non fixed size. I might be wording the question wrong. Sorry if that is true, and feel free to correct it.

Comment: you say u can use generate to create both dynamic an non dynamic containers. i thought the benefit of a dynamic container was that i dont default construct on declaration. Also when i try to create `std::array<some_obj, size> array;` i get `incomplete type is not allowed` error.

Comment: @AntonioDropulić the algorithm call happens at runtime, so it is non fixed. Is avoiding the size being determined on the algorithm call the problem that you try to solve? The size has to be known at some point, or else the program won't stop. When should the size be determined?

Comment: well a while loop allows you to loop forever. I dont feel that would be crazy. I would determine it in the lambda. when i satisfy my condition.
The accepted answer does that with the filter lambda.

Comment: @AntonioDropulić sure you can loop "forever" but if you add elements into a container within the loop, then surely you'll run out of memory eventually? There's no way to express the desire to stop generation from within a generator. As you see in Caleth's answer, they use a separate lambda for that. Is the ability to stop generation using a predicate what you are looking for?

Comment: If you would like we can continue this in chat tomorrow. I would love to learn from you.

Comment: yes that is what I'm looking for. I am not educated enought to realize why it can't be done in one predicate. I thought the separate predicate is a safety feature to ensure a finite container. I have no knowledge of the mentioned lib.

Comment: also in that while(true) you can use vector.push_back(), so, same problem, right?